# How to retrieve a list of all Airflow DAGs in Python?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, airflow

There is the CLI function `airflow dags list` which lists all DAGs in the current environment. Is there a similar function in the Python API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Airflow Rest API has [List DAGs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/get_dags) endpoint.

```
GET /dags
```

There is also official [Python client](https://github.com/apache/airflow-client-python) for the API so you can use it with Python easily.
You can see [example](https://github.com/apache/airflow-client-python/blob/master/airflow_client/docs/DAGApi.md#get_dags) how to set it for `get_dags`:

```
with client.ApiClient(configuration) as api_client:
    # Create an instance of the API class
    api_instance = dag_api.DAGApi(api_client)
    limit = 100
    offset = 0
    order_by = "order_by_example"
    tags = [
        "tags_example",
    ]
    only_active = True
    try:
        # List DAGs
        api_response = api_instance.get_dags(limit=limit, offset=offset, order_by=order_by, tags=tags, only_active=only_active)
        pprint(api_response)
    except client.ApiException as e:
        print("Exception when calling DAGApi->get_dags: %s\n" % e)
```

Comment: So this client is not included in apache-airflow? Kinda inconvenient having to add another dependency to the project.

Comment: It's a separated package

Comment: @EladKalif This client returns max of 100 dags even if you set the limit more than 100, did you check it?

Comment: @user1772390 by check it you mean what? The OP didnt raise concern regarding limits. You have offset paramter use it to iterate till no records left to fetch. If you belive there is a bug with the API then kindly open a github issue to the Airflow and we will look into it

Comment: Yes I customized the implementation for this as you have suggested. Raised the issue to OP. thanks for the help :-)